# Multiply operator applied to list(data structure)

Tags: python, list, multiplication, shallow-copy, python-datamodel

I'm reading [How to think like a computer scientist](http://openbookproject.net/thinkCSpy/) which is an introductory text for "Python Programming".

I want to clarify the behaviour of multiply operator (`*`) when applied to lists.

Consider the function **make_matrix**

```
def make_matrix(rows, columns):
"""
  >>> make_matrix(4, 2)
  [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
  >>> m = make_matrix(4, 2)
  >>> m[1][1] = 7
  >>> m
  [[0, 0], [0, 7], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
"""
return [[0] * columns] * rows
```

The actual output is

```
[[0, 7], [0, 7], [0, 7], [0, 7]]
```

The correct version of **make_matrix**  is :

```
def make_matrix(rows, columns):
"""
  >>> make_matrix(3, 5)
  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
  >>> make_matrix(4, 2)
  [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
  >>> m = make_matrix(4, 2)
  >>> m[1][1] = 7
  >>> m
  [[0, 0], [0, 7], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
"""
matrix = []
for row in range(rows):
    matrix += [[0] * columns]
return matrix
```

The reason why first version of **make_matrix** fails ( as explained in the book at 9.8 ) is that

*...each row is an alias of the other rows...*

I wonder why

```
[[0] * columns] * rows
```

causes *...each row is an alias of the other rows...*

but not

```
[[0] * columns]
```

i.e.  why  each `[0]` in a row is not an alias of other row element.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EVERYTHING in python are objects, and python never makes copies unless explicity asked to do so.

When you do

```
innerList = [0] * 10
```

you create a list with 10 elements, **all of them refering to the same `int` object *`0`***.

Since integer objects are **immutable**, when you do

```
innerList[1] = 15
```

You are changing the second element of the list so that it refers to another integer *`15`*. That always works because of *`int`* objects immutability.

That's why

```
outerList = innerList * 5
```

Will create a `list` object with 5 elements, each one is a reference to **the same `innerList`** just as above. But since `list` objects are **mutable**:

```
outerList[2].append('something')
```

Is the same as:

```
innerList.append('something')
```

Because they are two references to the **same `list` object**. So the element ends up in that single `list`. It appears to be duplicated, but the fact is that there is only one `list` object, and many references to it.

By contrast if you do

```
outerList[1] = outerList[1] + ['something']
```

Here you are **creating *another* `list` object** (using `+` with lists is an explicit copy), and assigning a reference to it into the second position of `outerList`. If you "append" the element this way (not really appending, but creating another list), `innerList` will be unaffected.

Comment: This only tells people why the wrong thing is the wrong thing, it doesn't offer a good solution. Solution: `outerList = [[0]*10 for _ in range(5)]` is Pythonic, and compact, and doesn't generate shallow-copies.

Answer (score -4):

lists are not primitives, they are passed by reference. A copy of a list is a pointer to a list (in C jargon). Anything you do to the list happens to all copies of the list and the copies of its contents unless you do a shallow copy.

```
[[0] * columns] * rows
```

Oops, we've just made a big list of pointers to [0]. Change one and you change them all.

Integers are not passed by reference, they are really copied, therefore [0] * contents is really making lots of NEW 0's and appending them to the list.

Comment: aha, Doesn't this seems like a special kind of behavior for a list of size 1. 
I heard a "Pythonista" do not like special cases(  as explained in the Zen of Python "...Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules...."  ).

Comment: Misleading. There is no such thing as "primitive" in python. EVERYTHING is an object and is passed by reference all the time, INCLUDING INTEGERS. In fact variables are just named references. The issue here is that the list is mutable, while ints are not.

Comment: example: a = 5 ; b = a ; print a is b # That returns True because a and b are references to the same object.