# What does [[]]*2 do in python?

Tags: python

```
A = [[]]*2

A[0].append("a")
A[1].append("b")

B = [[], []]

B[0].append("a")
B[1].append("b")

print "A: "+ str(A)
print "B: "+ str(B)
```

Yields:

```
A: [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
B: [['a'], ['b']]
```

One would expect that the A list would be the same as the B list, this is not the case, both append statements were applied to A[0] and A[1].

Why?

Comment: There's a very nice explanation of Python's * operator for list's in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974931/multiply-operator-applied-to-listdata-structure

Comment: @S. Lott: It seems quite clear to me: two very similar forms, [[]]*2 and [[],[]] yield very different results when operated upon in the same way. Why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`A = [[]]*2` creates a list with 2 identical elements: `[[],[]]`.
The elements are the same exact list.
So

```
A[0].append("a")
A[1].append("b")
```

appends both `"a"` and `"b"` to the same list.

`B = [[], []]` creates a list with 2 distinct elements.

```
In [220]: A=[[]]*2

In [221]: A
Out[221]: [[], []]
```

This shows that the two elements of `A` are identical:

```
In [223]: id(A[0])==id(A[1])
Out[223]: True

In [224]: B=[[],[]]
```

This shows that the two elements of `B` are different objects.

```
In [225]: id(B[0])==id(B[1])
Out[225]: False
```