# 2D Python list will have random results

Tags: python, list

I have created a 10 by 10 game board. It is a 2D list, with another list of 2 inside. I used 
`board = [[['O', 'O']] * 10 for x in range(1, 11)]`. So it will produce something like

['O', 'O'] ['O', 'O']...

['O', 'O'] ['O', 'O']...

Later on I want to set a single cell to have 'C' I use `board.gameBoard[animal.y][animal.x][0] = 'C'`
board being the class the gameBoard is in, and animal is a game piece, x & y are just ints. Some times it will work and the specified cell will become ['C', 'O'], other times it will fill the entire row with ['C', 'O']['C', 'O']['C', 'O']['C', 'O']
Does anyone know why that might be happening?

Comment: related: [Multiply operator applied to list(data structure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974931/multiply-operator-applied-to-listdata-structure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you're creating a whole bunch of references to the same list -- To demonstrate, consider:

```
[ [] ]*10
```

If you print the `id`s:

```
>>> print map(id,[ [] ]*10)
[958336, 958336, 958336, 958336, 958336, 958336, 958336, 958336, 958336, 958336]
```

you'll see they're all the same:

The easiest fix is to do something like:

```
[ [['O','O'] for _ in range(10)] for x in range(1, 11) ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry, a lot of people have fallen into the same trap as you.

`[['O', 'O']] * 10` creates 10 copies of [*the same list*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15036705/1907098). That means that when you change an element in one of the lists, the change is reflected in all the others.

Do this instead to create 10 separate lists:

```
[[['O', 'O'] for j in range(10)] for i in range(10)]  # or xrange in Python 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your board is getting multiple references to the same array. 
  You need to replace the `* 10` with another list comprehension.