# python list assigning to multiple variable with or without an multiple operator gets different result?

Tags: python

when I try to assign a list to 2 variables, the following 2 ways get different results?

```
# way1
a,b =  [[None,None],[None,None]]
# way2
c,d = [[None,None]]*2
```

a and b have different addresses on memory caches, while c and d have the same one.

```
print(id(a),id(b))
# out: 5243249856 5243249472

print(id(c),id(d))
# out: 5243246016 5243246016
```

The right-side lists are completely the same, the only difference is the way to create the list (way2 uses a '*' to expand the list). However, the left-side get different results. How is this happen? any one have any idea?

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974931/multiply-operator-applied-to-listdata-structure

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question, `[[None,None],[None,None]]`  creates a list with two references to two different lists, `[[None,None]]*2` creates a list with two references to the same list